# Uploading a .jar with php problem

Tags: php

I am building a php application.
I can easily upload an image or any other type of data, but not a .jar. Below my code:

**Upload.php**

```
<form action="getfile.php" method="post" name="uploadForm" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  ><br>
    <?php echo gettext("Image "); ?> 
        <input name="imagen" value="" type="file" id="imagen" />

    <?php echo gettext("Jar "); ?> 
        <input name="jarFile" value="" type="file" id="jarFile" />
</form>
```

**getfile.php**

```
$fileName = $_FILES['jar']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['jar']['type'];
//Check the extension
if (!strpos($fileType, "jar") ) {
    echo gettext("The simulation must be jar extension. Try again.");
}else{

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['jar']['tmp_name'], $path)){
       echo gettext("Simulation stored succesfully.");
    }else{
       echo gettext("Something happened. Try again. ");
    }
}
```

For images I am following the same aproach, but when I try to upload a jar file, I am always getting the error

> The simulation must be jar extension. Try again

and `$fileType` is empty. Is there some restriction at this point? Am I missing something??

Thanks in advance

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. Look into `$fileType` and see what it says

Comment: `$_FILES['jar']['type']` is empty. That field is not always populated.

Comment: and how could I check if the asset uploaded is a jar or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` property is unreliable (and populated by the browser). Your best bet is to retrieve the MIME file type:

```
$fhandle = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime_type = finfo_file($fhandle, $_FILES['jar']['tmp_name']);
```

The `$mime_type` should be `application/java-archive`.

**PHP >= 5.3.0**

Comment: The size of the .jar = 0, the type is empty and if I get rid of any if statement, I can see the error `Something happened. Try again. ` Is the jar upload allowed?? Could be the error in another part of the code?

Comment: The file didn't upload. Check your php.ini settings and make sure you have a hidden input called `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in your form.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that upload_max_filesize was not big enough. Thanks!